# Ordering within a MySQL Group function

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to run a Group function where the results are explicitly ordered within the function. Here is an example of the table structure (along with fabricated data)

```
id (int) | foo_id (int) | bar_id (int) | action (enum) | created (datetime)
1        | 17980        | 18           | added         | 2012-12-03 07:34:23
2        | 14321        | 17           | added         | 2013-01-06 07:34:23
3        | 9784         | 18           | added         | 2013-02-15 07:34:23
4        | 17980        | 18           | removed       | 2013-03-12 07:34:23
etc.
```

I want to the know the most recent action for each foo_id. Ideally I would run something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE bar_id = 18 GROUP BY foo_id ORDER BY created;
```

And the ideal result would be:

```
id | foo_id | bar_id | action  | created
3  | 9784   | 18     | added   | 2013-02-15 07:34:23
4  | 17980  | 18     | removed | 2013-03-12 07:34:23
```

For foo_id = 17980 two actions occurred. The first action added foo and the second removed it. My ideal Group function would just return the most recent action, as determined by the created field.

As far as I know the Group function does not accept order parameters. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `GROUP BY foo_id` and grab `MAX(created)` to get the most recent date for each `foo_id` and then `JOIN` back to your table to get all other columns for these values

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT foo_id, MAX(created) created
    FROM Table1
   WHERE bar_id = 18
   GROUP BY foo_id
) q ON t.foo_id = q.foo_id 
   AND t.created = q.created
 ORDER BY t.created;
```

Output:

```
| ID | FOO_ID | BAR_ID |  ACTION |             CREATED |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |   9784 |     18 |   added | 2013-02-15 07:34:23 |
|  4 |  17980 |     18 | removed | 2013-03-12 07:34:23 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93865/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

There is a `group_concat()` trick that you can use to get this information:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(id order by created desc), ',', 1) as id,
       foo_id, max(created) as MostRrecentCreated,
       substring_index(group_concat(bar_id order by created desc), ',', 1) as bar_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(action order by created desc), ',', 1) as action
from table
group by foo_id;
```

Two notes.  This converts the fields that use the logic to strings, so if you want them in another type, you need to convert them back.  Second, it assumes that `action` does not contain any commas.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get the desired output. It is called group wise maximum. Those are listed [here](http://jan.kneschke.de/2007/2/15/groupwise-max/).

Mostly people use the approach mentioned by peterm.